# Prime ideals $2 = p \cdot p'$

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, quadratic-forms

Let $d_K$ be the discriminant of the quadratic number field $K = \mathbb Q(\sqrt{d})$.

How can I show that for the prime $p=2$, we have: $$2 \not | d_k, \; d \equiv 1 \pmod{8} \Rightarrow (2) = \mathcal p \mathcal p',$$ where $\mathcal p \not = \mathcal p'$ are prime ideals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $d \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$, the ring of integers of $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{d})$ is $\Bbb Z[\frac{1+\sqrt{d}}{2}]$. The minimal polynomial of $\frac{1+\sqrt{d}}{2}$ is $x^2-x-\frac{d-1}{4}$. If we suppose that $d \equiv 1 \pmod{8}$, then $2 \mid \frac{d-1}{4}$, so $x^2-x-\frac{d-1}{4}$ reduces mod $2$ to $x^2-x=x(x-1)$, which is a product of two distinct irreducible polynomials. Thus $2$ splits in $\Bbb Z[\frac{1+\sqrt{d}}{2}]$ as the product of two distinct prime ideals.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer! Why does follow from $2 | d_K$ that $(2) = \mathcal p^2$ ?

Comment: (I read this in a side note...)

Comment: @StMan it is a general fact that primes dividing the discriminant ramify.

Comment: And other question: Are there explicit generators of $\mathcal p, \mathcal p'$ ?